# rate and review within an app

Tags: android, google-play

Right now in my apps i have a link that directs the user to the app page in the market so they can rate and review the app. Im curious if there is an api where they can review directly in the app and ad it to the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish there were, but whenever I think about this, I come to the conclusion that there probably isn't.  This would more than likely be due to the fact that your application could "Automatically" send a rating/review without the user ever knowing so.

I would love to be proved wrong though.

Comment: Ha thats a very good point. I was just wishin and hoping i guess. I guess we'd know about it if we could